# Rails: How to lock ActiveRecords in order to avoid collisions in data trafic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

How can we lock an ActiveRecord and complete the operations on it before allowing another thread or request to make changes to the ActiveRecord?

> I am building an eCommerce site which currently has a huge discount
>   campaign. Only one unit of your product left. And many people want to
>   buy it at the exact same time. In such scenario, I need to lock the
>   product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails, you could use `with_lock`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic/with_lock